# How to refresh element in a different file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I'm developing primefaces based www application. One of my components [tree] is defined in .xhtml file. I would like to to refresh it from different place [ file ]. Is there any way to do this? I've tried classic

```
update="nameOfElement"
```

but it doesn't work at all. I don' need an specific code line by line. Just in general how to do this and is it even possible. If not - > can I use primepush for this? How to pass the tree structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` attribute in many Primefaces components will typically take a space delimited string of component ids that should be redrawn after a JSF Ajax request/response has occurred.  The following entries can be put into the update attribute:

- **@this** will update just this component
- **@parent** will update the parent `UINamingContainer` of this component
- **@form** will update all components within this components form
- **nameOfElement** will only update a component with the following element if it is relative to the same UINamingContainer.

So it can't seem to find the component with this id, just because it is in a different `UINamingContainer`, Eg. `<form> <h:dataTable> etc`.

Using the `:` prefix will resolve the id relative to the view root of the page.

```
update=":nameOfElement"
```

This should be able to find the element if it is not inside of a naming container...

But what if it is inside of a form that prepends its id?

```
update=":nameOfForm:nameOfElement"
```

Then the above should find the form prefixed element relative to the view root.

Comment: ok, so it doesn't matter where the element is? I can update component which is in different file. Yes?

Comment: @iie You are talking about a different file as in `<ui:include src="otherfile.xhtml" />` correct?  Yes you can ajax update any component on the page because it includes both files on the page.

Comment: and what if there is no section like this?

Comment: @iie Then there is no component by that name on the page... How can you Ajax update a component that isn't on the page?  Do you understand what `update` does?  Do you understand what Ajax is?

Comment: well thank You for Your response. That was what I've been expecting = /. I need to find some workaround for this.